# how to filter arry of JSON objects like [{'id':1,name:'a'},{'id':2,name:'b'},{'id':3,name:'c'}] and return only unmatched result

Tags: javascript, angular

```
var data = [{
    "bankId": "67",

    "bankName": "TESTBANKJU",

  },
  {
    "bankId": "52",

    "bankName": "Test",

  },
  {
    "bankId": "50",

    "bankName": "Sanjyot Bank",

  },
  {
    "bankId": "45",

    "bankName": "TestDemo",

  },
];
```

and get results whose bankId is not 67 and 52

```js
data.filter(x => x.bankId != '67' || x.bankId != '52');

data = [{
    "bankId": "50",

    "bankName": "Sanjyot Bank",

  },
  {
    "bankId": "45",

    "bankName": "TestDemo",

  }
]
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: You literally wrote "and" in your description but wrote "or" in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you need an AND condition. The OR returns every item, because one or both check is always `true`.

```js
var data = [{ bankId: "67", bankName: "TESTBANKJU" }, { bankId: "52", bankName: "Test" }, { bankId: "50", bankName: "Sanjyot Bank" }, { bankId: "45", bankName: "TestDemo" }]
    result = data.filter(x => x.bankId !== '67' && x.bankId !== '52');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `&&` operator.

```js
var data = [{
  "bankId": "67",

  "bankName": "TESTBANKJU",
}, {
  "bankId": "52",

  "bankName": "Test",
}, {
  "bankId": "50",

  "bankName": "Sanjyot Bank",
}, {
  "bankId": "45",

  "bankName": "TestDemo",
}, ]

var filtered_data = data.filter(item => (item.bankId != "67" && item.bankId != "52"))

console.log(filtered_data)
```